# Transform for geometry in JTS

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools, jts-topology-suite

I am using [JTS](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jts/index.html) in my application, and I want to transform the geometry from longitude and latitude to pixel.

And the algorithm for this translation has been providered by an interface:

```
public double[] fromLngLatToPixel(double lat, double lng);
```

Now I have to read the coordinates for the source geometry ,transform the coordinates and then create a new geometry.

However, I found that `JTS` has a transfrom method like this:

```
public static Geometry transform(Geometry geom, MathTransform transform);
```

But I do not know to to implement the `MathTransform` according to `fromLngLatToPixel`.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to know the maths behind creating your own transform then you will want to follow the [Affine Transform tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/affinetransform.html).

However, since you tag [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) in your question, you can take the shortcut of using [`RenderUtilities.worldToScreenTransform`](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/renderer/lite/RendererUtilities.html#worldToScreenTransform-org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope-java.awt.Rectangle-). You simply pass in the bounds of the screen in world coordinates and the size of the screen as a `Rectangle`.

```
public static AffineTransform worldToScreenTransform(ReferencedEnvelope mapExtent,
                                                 Rectangle paintArea)
```